# Why cant I get transmute to average these two values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a transmute function of average productivity between two months, but I keep messing it up somehow. Not sure if its my bad math or bad dplyr usage. Here is the script, including the dput:

```
##################################################
#        Productivity Script for Stack           #
##################################################

# Loading Data:

work <- structure(list(Case_Number = 30:40, Year = c("2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021"), Month_Number = c("9", "9", "9", "9", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10"), Month_Name = c("September", "September", 
"September", "September", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October"), Day_Number = c(27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Day_Name = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"), Time_Wake = c(600L, 730L, 
650L, 830L, 630L, 630L, 830L, 722L, 641L, 800L, 720L), Start_Work = c(950L, 
1108L, 1430L, 955L, 1313L, 1125L, 1636L, 1126L, 1027L, 1323L, 
1003L), End_Work = c(1504L, 1430L, 1933L, 1335L, 1330L, 2130L, 
1636L, 1600L, 1730L, 1800L, 1739L), Mins_Sleep = c(310L, 390L, 
350L, 450L, 390L, 390L, 510L, 452L, 310L, 360L, 500L), Workout_Y_N = c("Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y"), Workout_Before_After = c("Before", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Before", "Before", "Before", NA, "Before", "Before"
), Time_Workout = c(730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 915L, 1000L, 815L, 
NA, 900L, 740L), Work_Environment = c("Office", "Office", "Office", 
"Office", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Office", 
"Office"), Coffee_Cups = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L), Tea_Cups = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
2L), Mins_Work = c(266L, 196L, 198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 
343L, 207L, 263L), Weather = c(NA, NA, "Sunny", "Sunny", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

# Calculate Productivity Growth:

september_work <- work %>% 
  filter(Month_Name=="September") %>% 
  summarize(September_Mins = (sum(Mins_Work))) # calcs sep work

october_work <- work %>% 
  filter(Month_Name == "October") %>% 
  summarize(October_Mins = (sum(Mins_Work, na.rm = T))) # calcs oct work

work_growth <- ((october_work - september_work) / september_work) # calc growth
work_growth # gives percentage of productivity growth

# Create average of work between October and September:

work %>% 
  transmute(avg_month_work = sum(september_work + october_work)/2)
```

Comment: The sample data only has August and September...

Comment: Sorry dunno what happened there but I'm about to edit it now so its correct.

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Are you looking for `sum(september_work + october_work)/2` or `mean(c(september_work$September_Mins, october_work$October_Mins))`

Comment: I'm looking for the mean of October and September Mins_Work. Basically (October_Mins + September_Mins)/2

Comment: How about `transmute(avg_month_work = (september_work + october_work)/2)`? You don't need to `sum` all of the columns into one (which would be better done with `summarize`.

Comment: When I do that, I get a 46x repeating value of 5342.5.

Comment: Disregard, I didn't take into account your data munging ...

Comment: Can you show the expected output given this sample data? RonakShah already asked for it, but it isn't clear to me how it should actually look given your comment-reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an all-in-one that should work with multiple months/years.  It provides a rolling % difference between consecutive months and and a cumulative monthly average

```
work %>%
  #get sums by month
  group_by(Month_Name, Month_Number, Year) %>%
  summarize(monthly_mins = sum(Mins_Work)) %>%
  #put in order
  mutate(Month_Number = as.numeric(Month_Number),
         counter = 1) %>%
  arrange(Year, Month_Number) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #set up rolling pct change calc and cumulative average
  transmute(
    Year, 
    Month_Name,
    pct_change = (monthly_mins / lag(monthly_mins) - 1) * 100,
    avg_month_work = cumsum(monthly_mins) / cumsum(counter)
  )
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for. One question: why do you do the ungroup function? I always get confused by why people use it.

Comment: Ungrouping leave your dataframe looking like it's grouped (not as many rows, aggregated info), but removes the grouping structures that exist behind-the-scenes. For some functions, if you apply them to grouped data, they are going to act on each group separately.  If you run lag on the grouped data, it looks within each group and finds only 1 row.  If you run lag after ungrouping, it treats the whole df as a single group.  You can take that line out and see the difference in your result.  tl;dr: if you continue to transform your entire df  after your summarize, it can prevent weirdness.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the thorough explanation!